# Android приложение слетает когда долго находится в фоновом режиме

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Запускаем программу, переключаемся между задачами и через некоторое время вернувшись в свою программу обнаруживаем, что она, вместо того чтобы восстановить своё состояние, перезапускается. Как побороть этот эффект?

Comment: В консоли есть ошибки? Если нет, то возможно система банально освобождает память, прибивая ваши активити.

Comment: В консоли нет ошибок.. и никак не избежать прибивания?

Comment: Никак. Это особенность работы мобильных ОС - приложение в фоне может быть прибито в любой момент. Если вам нужна фоновая работа - для этого нужно делать сервис.